# SwiftUI sheet doesn't retain same color during video loading

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My `.sheet` is using `.presentationBackground(.thinMaterial)` for transparent background. It works across all my `.sheets`, but the one that is loading my video preview (`AVKit`) into the view it seems to be using the system colors and then as soonest the video is fully loaded it changes colors to `.presentationBackground(.thinMaterial)`.

This is what it looks like as soonest I tap the video to bring the sheet into view:

[image]

And this is a split second later:

[image]

Code for loading video:

```
func loadVideoProperties() {
        isLoading = true // Show loading indicator
        let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
        let keys = ["playable"]

        asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isLoading = false // Hide loading indicator
                var error: NSError?
                let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "playable", error: &error)

                if status == .loaded {
                    self.isVideoReady = true // Video is ready
                    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: asset))
                } else if let error = error {
                    print("Error loading video properties: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Code for my `sheet`:

```
.sheet(item: $videoPreviewURL) { videoURL in
      VideoPreviewView(videoURL: videoURL.url)
      .presentationDetents([.height(560)])
      .presentationBackground(.thinMaterial)
}
```

How to keep it always transparent regardless of the video loading.

Comment: This needs a [mre]

Comment: Where are you calling load from? It is unusual to use dispatch in SwiftUI because Views are simple structs that have no lifetime, that's why they give us `.task`